# Docker and Spring Boot

Tags: docker, spring-boot

We have many Spring Boot applications & are starting to 'containerize' using Docker.

Right now, we have Eureka running (Spring Boot) and client applications (all other Spring Boot applications), in their application.yml files have:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

This works **before** dockerization.

Now, when I dockerize a (Eureka client) application (the Eureka servier is still not-dockerized), I can't use "localhost" since Eureka doesn't run in the same container. I was able to connect to Eureka by copying its url (192.168.2.77) so the above now becomes:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://192.168.2.77:8761/eureka/
```

This works.

**Question 1**:

When the Eureka server gets dockerized, how would I pass in its url to client applications? I presume that I can set the above to be something like:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${eurekaURL}
```

and when starting the container use the "*-e eurekaURL:xyz*" but how do I get the Eureka server IP ... ideally, dynamically?

**Question 2**:

The Spring Boot applications don't have ports assigned. In their application.yml files, I use:

```
server.port: 0
```

so that any available port is assigned.

However, to expose ports so can access the running web applications, in the docker command I have to expose a port (... -p 8080:8080 ...). How is this possible since the "available port" isn't known until the Spring Boot application starts?

Comment: You can create docker networks and make those containers, which should communicate, part of the same network. You could also bind all the containers to `--net=host` so it is actually possible to communicate via `localhost`.

Comment: When you decide to use `--net=host` you do not have to publish ports, since they are opened directly on `localhost`.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into --net=host

Comment: just tried that; ran service-registry with --net=host. it was inaccessible via the browser using 'localhost' and ip address using known port. when i do 'docker ps' there are no ports exposed so not understanding this approach :(

Comment: Do EXPOSE a port in your Dockerfile?

Comment: Ahh, it is a random port..There is the Option -P which publishes all Ports from within the container. maybe try this.

Comment: I am exposing ports for each service; not doing the dynamic port business right now. Earlier, when I was & doing -P, then no ports were exposed b/c none are EXPOSE(d) in the Dockerfile which is used by maven (POM) to build the image.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:**: You can use alias for `eureka` container and have one network for all of your services. For example you can have one `docker-compose` with all of your containers and `defaultZone: http://eureka-service:8761/eureka/`. `eureka-service` is your alias for `eureka` instance.

For example you may have [application.yml](https://github.com/ExampleDriven/spring-boot-docker-example/blob/master/echo-service/src/main/resources/application.yml) for service

```
 client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${eureka_url:http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/}
```

Example for [docker-compose](https://github.com/ExampleDriven/spring-boot-docker-example/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). Docker-compose will create one network for all services

```
  eureka-server:
    image: eureka-server
    ports:
     - "8761:8761"
```

[Full github example](https://github.com/ExampleDriven/spring-boot-docker-example)

**Question 2:**: For this I would use some gateway. For example proxy which will be able to distribute requests to certain microservice. [The API Gateway Pattern](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/28/the-api-gateway-pattern-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iv) (based on Zuul proxy). Services within one network with eureka will figure out which port each service uses.

In the example above they use also zuul gateway. With gateway you would not need expose ports for each microservice. And you can have some aditional monitoring and security.

Comment: i tried your suggestion to question1 so have 2 services register with eureka. service1 still cannot execute restful to service2 using the ip address indicated w/ 'unknown host exception'. i can see ip addresses via eureka/apps/ (172.21.0.2, 172.21.0.3) but cannot connect tho those either

Comment: @maspen `service1` is trying to call `service1`? If yes dont use IP addresses. You can use service name like `eureka-service` but eg `service1` when you call `service1` from `service2` and vice versa. If you are trying to call `service1` outside docker network you will need to expose port. but you said that you have randomly generated ports for your services. So this is tricky and there should comes `gateway` which will be able to play with `eureka` and will know about ports for services.

Comment: I am exposing "static" ports (ie not worrying about dynamic ports right now). my rest template calls http://SERVICE2/.... but when it executes, getting unknown host exception b/c eureka associates 'service2' with something link c286a550d1a9:service2:8083